# Having issues connecting Access database with ASP/ADO

Tags: asp-classic

I am trying to connect to an access database with ADO. Below is my script. The access database is called ADOTesting1.mdb. I'm thinking it has to do with the path. This is where the file is located.

C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyWeb

```
<%
Dim conn
Dim rs
Dim rdsql
set conn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Provider="Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
conn.Open "c:/inetpub/wwwroot/MyWeb/ADOTesting1.mdb"

set rs=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
rs.Open "Select * from Customers", conn

for each x in rs.fields
    response.write(x.name)
    response.write(" = ")
    response.write(x.value)
next
%>
```

Comment: I suggest you tagging your question with `vb.net` and `ms-access` to attract more readers.

Comment: @aemxdp What does [tag:vb.net] have to do with this question? Do you actually mean [tag:vbscript]?, that would be relevant.

Comment: Do not store or link to your database from inside the web root. Store the database outside of the website scope and assign it the relevant permissions. If its inside your web root it is easily assessible to everyone. Infact i'd go further and say don't use Access at all, SQL Server is a better more secure modern option also widely available through SQL Server Express editions. No excuses for using MDB files anymore.

Comment: @Lankymart, whoops, my apologies, you're right.

Comment: What error message are you getting?  There are several reasons why you may be having problems.  It could indeed be that the path is wrong, it could be that the IUSR account doesn't have permission to access the database, it could be that you haven't enabled 32 bit applications - the Jet OLEDB driver is 32 bit only.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use `Server.MapPath` to map the physical path to the website path.

Instead of:

```
conn.Open "c:/inetpub/wwwroot/MyWeb/ADOTesting1.mdb"
```

Try:

```
conn.Open Server.MapPath("/MyWeb/ADOTesting1.mdb")
```

or whatever the relative path is to your web root "/".